# Ajax login returning incorrect details even when details are correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax, jQuery and JavaScript and this is more of a learning exercise for myself to brush up on some skills. I want to move away from login pages that are separate pages (i.e. loginForm.php that sends data to login.php which then redirects to a logged in section) and want to move down a jQuery ajax route.

I have built my index page as follows:

```
<form id="login_form">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="user_name"  name="user_name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password"  name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="login"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have set my JavaScript up like so:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
    username=$("#user_name").val();
    password=$("#password").val();
    console.log(username + " " + password);
    var info = {username:username, password:password};
    console.log(info);
    var sub = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(html){
        if(html=='true')
        {
            $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");
        }
    },
    beforeSend:function()
    {
         $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
    },
    error: function(response) { console.log(response); }
    });
    console.log(sub);
    return false;
});
```

when I `console.log(info)` it tells me in the log that this is an object and it has the information that I need to send. So I'm sure that this part so far is okay. The following script is my login.php:

```
<?php
include('secure.php'); // includes PDO database connection here

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sel = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM aaUsers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$sel->execute();
$count = $sel->rowCount();
    if ( $count >= 1) {
        echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false";
    }
?>
```

The info is passed across to here and then this script runs, however, when I `console.log(sub)` I can see that the `responseText = ""` and this is causing my script to fail over. would someone be able to inform me where I have gone wrong, I feel like I'm doing everything right, just that there seems to be somewhere I have gone wrong.

Comment: Put `console.log(html)` in your AJAX success function to find out what  your PHP script is returning. It could be as simple as needing to `trim()` the whitespace off your returned data...

Comment: Im guessing your php is failing and you have error reporting turned off

Answer (score 0):

Are you using chrome, or firefox (with firebug)?  Open the developer console and watch what comes back from the AJAX call.  If it's blank there, then as scrowler has put well, your php is faulty.  You could also create a quick non-ajax testing form to post the two variables the ol' fashioned way.

```
<html>
<body><form action=login.php method=post><input name=username/> <input name=password/> <input type=submit></form></body></html>
```

Fill in the blanks and hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

Turns out I had called:

```
$sel = $db->prepare(...);
```

instead of:

```
$sel = $conn->prepare(...);
```

works fine now, thank you for your suggestions for looking at my php script.